# Test database record has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The expect block isn't working like I'd expect it to. I have one expectation, `should change the name` :

```
let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  
let!(:parent_folder) { FactoryGirl.create(:folder, user_id: user.id) }

before { sign_in user }

describe '#update' do
     let(:new_name) { Faker::Lorem.word }
     let(:request) { patch :update, id: parent_folder.id, folder: { name: new_name, parent_id: nil, user_id: user.id } }

     it 'should change the name' do
         expect {
             request
         }.to change(parent_folder, :name).from(parent_folder.name).to(new_name)
     end
end
```

And it results in:

```
  2) FoldersController#update should change the name
     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected #name to have changed from "consequatur" to "molestias", but did not change
```

Why is this? I promise you the change is occuring:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
SELECT  "folders".* FROM "folders"  WHERE "folders"."user_id" = ? AND "folders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
SAVEPOINT active_record_1
UPDATE "folders" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "folders"."id" = 1
RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

**Update**

My update action:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.update(folder_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Works perfectly when I do it myself in the browser...

Comment: Just as a trial, three variants: 1) Use `let!(..)` instead of lazily assigned `let()`. 2) Write `patch :update, id: parent_folder.id, folder: { name: new_name, parent_id: nil, user_id: user.id }` inside the expect block instead of a variable. 3) Implement both.

Comment: `UPDATE "folders" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "folders"."id" = 1` does not show the change occuring.  I think you have a problem with your update code.  Can you update your question with the code for your update action?

Comment: @infused Done! Works in an integration spec though...

Comment: I can also write other unit specs to assert that the notice is set to 
`'Folder was successfully updated.'` so I think the update action is fine

Comment: @vint-i-vuit Thanks, but no difference

Comment: @Starkers, I see the problem now.  Your parent_folder object needs to be reloaded.  I submitted a new answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your parent_folder object needs to be reloaded in order to see the change.  Change your expectation to use `parent_folder.reload.name` instead do this:

```
it 'should change the name' do
  expect { 
    request 
  }.to change{ parent_folder.reload.name }.from(parent_folder.name).to(new_name)
end
```

Comment: Hmm...that gets me: `'change' requires either an object and message ('change(obj, :msg)') or a block ('change { }'). You passed an object but no message.`

Comment: Actually did what the error message said and now it works :P Thanks

Comment: Did you use `change(parent_folder.reload, :name)`?  If so, I'll update my answer for others who stumble upon it.

Comment: I did edit your answer with the change for future stumblers...not sure what happened to it! Ah well, this is what's currently in my spec:

`expect {
        request
      }.to change{parent_folder.reload.name}.from(parent_folder.name).to(new_name)`